# Как передать в функцию параметром список значений без использования stl

Tags: c++

Псевдокод:

```
template<typename T>
bool fun(T a, list_of_parametrs my_list){
if (a in my_list) {return true;}
else {return false;}
}
```

**Каким образом можно осуществить передачу параметра** `list_of_parametrs my_list` в функцию? Да так, чтобы ещё этот `list_of_parametrs` мог оказаться разной длины, к примеру что-то на подобии `[1,2,3,4]` или `[name_1, name_2]`. Без использования стандартных контейнеров и алгоритмов.

Comment: Навелосипедить аналогичные контейнеры, нет?

Comment: @VTT а проще никак?

Comment: Variadic functions не подойдут? которые в Си - `va_list`, `va_start`?? https://stackoverflow.com/a/1579732/3503216

Comment: @vegorov Уж лучше тогда variadic templates.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat ну там в ответе есть ссылка на википедию на статью про Variadic Functions, там и про вариант с шаблонами на C++ пример есть

Comment: @vegorov так тоже можно, но не очень удобно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Синтаксис с квадратными скобками (`fun(foo, [a,b,c])`) получить невозможно.

Можно получить синтаксис с фигурными скобками (`fun(foo, {a,b,c})`), используя `std::initializer_list` (либо стандартные контейнеры, которые сами его используют).

`std::initializer_list` - вещь "магическая", и не может быть написана на стандартном С++. Без него никак.

---

Можно использовать variadic templates, вообще без скобок (`fun(foo, a,b,c)`):

```
template <typename T, typename ...P>
bool fun(T a, P ... my_list)
{
    T array[] {my_list...};
    for (const auto &it : array)
        std::cout << it << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

---

Теоретически, можно получить вместо `fun(foo, {a,b,c})` что-то вроде `fun(foo, bar{a,b,c})` либо `fun(foo, bar(a,b,c))`.

Но тогда придется много возиться с шаблонами и вручную переписывать часть `<type_traits>`, что выглядит неразумно.