# Шаблонная функция проверяющая наличие одного аргумента в другом

Tags: c++, алгоритм, c++11

Для проверки ввода пользователя я решил создать шаблонную функцию, которая проверяет введённые данные на корректность, а именно сверяет со списком разрешённых значений.

```
template <typename T>
bool ContainsIn(T a, std::initializer_list<T> my_list) {
    for (auto &it : my_list) if (a == it) return true;
    return false;
}
```

Вот пример того как это может работать:

```
std::initializer_list<int> Options = { 1,2,3,4,5 };
std::cin >> Input;
if (ContainsIn(Input, Options)){
// code
} else
// code
```

Мне сильно понравилась возможность использовать такую функцию из-за её возможности принимать не только целочисленные типы, но и, к примеру, `std::string`. Да и тем более написанная функция заменяет очень удобный оператор `in` из Python, где им крайне удобно пользоваться.
Но я столкнулся с проблемой, когда требуется проверить пользовательский ввод (ну или что-то другое) на наличие в **большом списке значений**.

[Вот здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/954397/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-stdinitializer-list) я описал эту проблему, где мне намекнули о возможной [проблеме XY](http://xyproblem.info/). В связи с этим появился новый вопрос тесно связанный со старым: **а стоило ли использовать такую функцию или есть другие, альтернативные варианты?** Код пишется в соответствии с учебными требованиями и использование библиотеки `С++ stl` **строго запрещено**, поэтому никакие векторы и другие прелести реального написания кода на С++ мне недоступны. Примерную реализацию вышеописанной функции мне подсказали [вот тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/951481/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-stl).

Comment: Я бы точно использовал или `set`, или `unordered_set`. Линейно перебирать 100000 элементов (как вы намекнули в своем предыдущем вопросе) - брр...

Comment: Ах, да... с учетом запрета на применение stl - отсортированный массив и бинарный поиск. Или собственная реализация хеш-таблицы. А если у вас вообще последовательные значения - как пример от 1 до 100000 - то просто кодом :)

Comment: @ARHovsepyan я могу ошибаться, но разве Utility library это stl? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility

Comment: @AlexIdest.   вы не ошибаетесь